# Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: error with Enzyme - help diagnosing?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I'm trying to use Enzyme to test React UI components in a create-react-app application. I have one basic test component working using mount. This suggests (to me at least), that I have enzyme and its dependencies set up correctly.

Whenever I try to run a test on one of my more complex components, I get an error such as:

```
Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
      at invariant (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:55:15)
      at createFiberFromTypeAndProps (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:9958:11)
      at createFiberFromElement (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:9979:15)
      at reconcileSingleElement (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:13654:23)
      at reconcileChildFibers (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:13711:35)
      at reconcileChildren (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:14078:28)
      at updateHostComponent (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:14423:3)
      at beginWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:15087:14)
      at performUnitOfWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17820:12)
      at workLoop (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17860:24)
      at renderRoot (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17946:7)
      at performWorkOnRoot (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18837:7)
      at performWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18749:7)
      at performSyncWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18723:3)
      at requestWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18592:5)
      at scheduleWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18401:5)
      at scheduleRootUpdate (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19069:3)
      at updateContainerAtExpirationTime (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19097:10)
      at updateContainer (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19154:10)
      at ReactRoot.render (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19416:3)
      at /Users/eric/Development/roadmapsftw/develop/web/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19556:14
      at unbatchedUpdates (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18952:10)
      at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19552:5)
      at Object.render (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19613:12)
      at Object.render (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/build/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:352:114)
      at new ReactWrapper (node_modules/enzyme/build/ReactWrapper.js:130:16)
      at mount (node_modules/enzyme/build/mount.js:21:10)
      at Context.<anonymous> (tests/test-navigation-Login.js:20:21)
```

When I google the error message itself, I get a lot of hits suggesting a component import is wrong. However, I doubt that is the case here, because the components run successfully in multiple browsers; I just cannot seem to create them with Enzyme using either mount() or shallow().

I think my project setup is correct for Enzyme; I put together a really basic set of components and a test for them, and that test is able to successfully mount(). So I don't think it is a problem with any of the suggested setupTest.js configuration (e.g. setting up an adapter), or how I'm invoking the test script.

I'm really unclear how to debug from here. The start of the stack trace is the line in my test script where I mount a component named Login. Here is the mount statement for that component from the test script:

```
const mounted = mount(
  <IntlProvider locale='en'>
    <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/Login']}>
      <TestContainer state={loginState}>
        <Login />
      </TestContainer>
    </MemoryRouter>
  </IntlProvider>
)
```

Here are the import statements for those components in the test script that is failing.

```
import { IntlProvider } from 'react-intl'
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { TestContainer } from './TestUtils.js'
import Login from '../src/navigation/Login'
```

The Login component works fine in the browser when accessed via the Home component; it is imported in the Home component with the following import statement:

```
import Login from '../navigation/Login'
```

The only difference between the test script that fails and the application that works is that the Container component is different. However, my super-simple test where mount works uses the same test Container component imported the same way.

Relevant versions from package.json:

```
"react": "^16.6.3",
"react-dom": "^16.6.3",
"react-intl": "^2.7.2",
"react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
"react-scripts": "2.1.1",
"enzyme": "^3.7.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.7.0",
```

Any suggestions on how to find what the failure condition here is? I'm tearing my hair out at this point.

Answer (score 1):

OK, when taking one more pass through the question, I noticed that one of my import statements actually included the file suffix rather than omitting it. I thought I'd configured the project so that I could skip suffixes. That is working for normal builds, but is failing in test runs. So if I add ".jsx" to the import of the Login component in the test script, my test now works.

Now off to figure out why this is the case; it wasn't a problem in a prior project where I wasn't using create-react-app and had therefore built the webpack.config.js manually.